# Xamarin.GradleBindings causes 'm2repository was not found' error

Tags: android, xamarin

Trying to use Visual Studio extension [Xamarin.GradleBindings](https://github.com/EgorBo/Xamarin.GradleBindings) and upon first attempt to use it, it prompts for the location of Android SDK. Providing the path to this folder resulted in:

```
ERROR: C:\...\androidk-sdk\extras\android\m2repository was not found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Android SDK manager (remembering to run as Administrator!) and install `Extras > Local Maven repository for Support Libraries`